# ffmpeg alters color scheme when converting images to a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert a sequence of png images to a video. Unfortunately the video though playing exactly what i want alters the colors.

The command used to convert the images:

> ffmpeg -framerate 30 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4

The original image colors:
[image: Color scheme in image]

The colors as displayed in the video.

[image: Color scheme in video]

How can I circumvent this altering of the colors?

**EDIT**
I found the answer as posted below.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Why are the widths of the two images different?

Comment: I screenshoted the results from the video at a different scale. I switched machines and still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the video-player used.
I played the video on two different machines both with Ubuntu 16.04.

Totem Movie Player (Default on Ubuntu) gives the distorted colors.
VLC Media Player yields correct colors. (Ubuntu 16.04)
VLC Media Player yields correct colors. (Windows 7)
Windows Media Player yields correct colors. (Windows 7)